# Estimating distance between two features in a shape file using Python

Tags: python, automation, arcgis, data-extraction

I am new to ArcGIS and trying to learn how I should make it work with Python.

I have a few points plotted on ArcGIS software. Now I want to measure the distance between those points using Python. Say I have 7 points (A,B,C,D,E,F,G). I want to measure the distance between points A and B, A and C, A and D, and so on. I know it is simple just do it in ArcGIS but wanted to learn how I should do it in Python.

If there is a way to do it exactly or if there is any better alternative, any leads would help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with ArcGis and you do not specify if you need a 2D distance or a 3D distance or a non-euclidian distance. So my answer may not be appropriate.
The 2D distance between 2 points is based on Pythagore's theorem:
d = sqrt( (y2-y1)**2 + (x2-x1)**2))

In python (2 or 3), it would be:

```
import math
d = math.sqrt((y2-y1)**2 + (x2-x1)**2)
```

For those who are afraid of typing "sqrt", there is now (since python3.8) a math.dist() function:

```
import math
d = math.dist((x1,x2), (y1,y2))
```

If your data points are in lists, math.dist shines because if will compute all your distances in a single call and return a list of distances.

For a 3D distance,  we are back to Pythagore's theorem:

```
d = math.sqrt( (z2-z1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2 + (x2-x1)**2)
```

And if you need a more accurate answer that take into account that the earth is not a perfect sphere, you should search for "delft stack haversine".
DuckDuckGo (duckduckgo.com) will be your friend.